# How to get filename and line number in crash backtrace from my DKMS module?

Tags: crash-dumps, dkms

I'm building a Linux module, on a Debian distribution, using DKMS, and I have a kernel freeze that I need to debug.

I've installed the `crash` command line tool, with the kernel debug symbols.
When a freeze happens, I have a crash file which I load with the `crash` command, and I can see the filenames and line numbers for each of the lines from the kernel trace, but when it is about my module, I don't have any filename, nor line number.

Here is an example:

```
WARNING: active task ffff98d215239e80 on cpu 1 not found in PID hash

      KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/boot/vmlinux-4.19.0-8-amd64
    DUMPFILE: /var/crash/202004292108/dump.202004292108  [PARTIAL DUMP]
        CPUS: 12
        DATE: Wed Apr 29 21:07:00 2020
      UPTIME: 00:13:32
LOAD AVERAGE: 0.62, 0.57, 0.37
       TASKS: 886
    NODENAME: debian
     RELEASE: 4.19.0-8-amd64
     VERSION: #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1+deb10u1 (2020-04-27)
     MACHINE: x86_64  (3700 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 16 GB
       PANIC: "BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000018"
         PID: 15775
     COMMAND: "douaned"
        TASK: ffff98d215239e80  [THREAD_INFO: ffff98d215239e80]
         CPU: 1
       STATE: EXIT_DEAD (PANIC)

crash> bt -l
PID: 15775  TASK: ffff98d215239e80  CPU: 1   COMMAND: "douaned"
 #0 [ffff98d36e843870] machine_kexec at ffffffff87656967
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./arch/x86/include/asm/mem_encrypt.h: 75
 #1 [ffff98d36e8438c8] __crash_kexec at ffffffff877213ad
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./kernel/kexec_core.c: 958
 #2 [ffff98d36e843990] crash_kexec at ffffffff877221fd
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./include/linux/compiler.h: 219
 #3 [ffff98d36e8439a8] oops_end at ffffffff8762a0ad
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./arch/x86/kernel/dumpstack.c: 334
 #4 [ffff98d36e8439c8] no_context at ffffffff876653ee
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./arch/x86/mm/fault.c: 808
 #5 [ffff98d36e843a20] __do_page_fault at ffffffff87665ab2
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./arch/x86/mm/fault.c: 1323
 #6 [ffff98d36e843a90] page_fault at ffffffff87e0114e
    /build/linux-AqT5hv/linux-4.19.98/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S: 1204
    [exception RIP: idr_find]
    RIP: ffffffff87d0b860  RSP: ffff98d36e843b40  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 0000000000000000  RBX: ffff98d20e848000  RCX: 0000000000000000
    RDX: 000000009456dad9  RSI: 0000000000005807  RDI: 0000000000000008
    RBP: ffff98d363bc3ae8   R8: 000000000001421d   R9: 00000000917bc5e0
    R10: ffff98d36e843bae  R11: 0000000000000049  R12: 0000000000000004
    R13: ffff98d226491480  R14: ffff98d206f28cfc  R15: ffff98d206f28d10
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./lib/idr.c: 177
 #7 [ffff98d36e843b40] find_get_pid at ffffffff8769e846
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./include/linux/pid.h: 71
 #8 [ffff98d36e843b48] netfiler_packet_hook at ffffffffc1962eda [douane]
 #9 [ffff98d36e843ce8] nf_hook_slow at ffffffff87c2eea4
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./net/netfilter/core.c: 512
#10 [ffff98d36e843d18] __ip_local_out at ffffffff87c3c8a7
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./include/linux/netfilter.h: 248
#11 [ffff98d36e843d70] ip_local_out at ffffffff87c3c927
    ./debian/build/build_amd64_none_amd64/./net/ipv4/ip_output.c: 123
...
```

*Have a look at the line #8.*

From the DKMS documentation, I found the `STRIPE=[#]` config to which I passed `no` in order to not remove the debug symbols (as the documentation says), but I still don't have any filenames nor line numbers.

Can anyone tell how can I have them showing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out !

You first need to know where is installed your kernel module file (`douane.ko` in my case, which is installed in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/`), then after having loaded the crash file, like it is shown in the question, you then need to load the module's debug symbols using the `mod` command:

```
crash> mod -s douane /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64/updates/dkms/douane.ko
     MODULE       NAME                       SIZE  OBJECT FILE
ffffffffc17f8040  douane                     28672 /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64/updates/dkms/douane.ko
```

From now on, using `bt -l` will show you also the line number from your kernel module source code too.